# Options In-memory queries against cached objects in .Net applications

Tags: c#, linq, caching, serialization, dynamic

I've developed a system that connects to external DBs and allows users to generate reports from these systems. Because I have no knowledge of the structure of these systems all my data sets are untyped which means I'm currently using DataTable's to store them.

In order to provide speedy analysis I use the Dynamic Linq library to perform linq queries over the datasets, I cache the datasets using Microsoft AppFabric. I also use protobuf-net (datatable extension) to serialize the size of the DataTable before adding to the cache.

To execute a query I first need to read the object from the cache, then de-serialize and finally execute the Dynamic Linq query.

I was wondering if anybody can recommend any alternative approaches? I think the limiting factor in my solution is having to rely on DataTables so for example I can't use any of the linq querying capabilities of protobuf-net.  I also have to take the DataTable in and out of cache and de-serialize each time before performing the query.

Comment: Is it possible to identify certain elements by a tag?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by a tag? At the moment each element stored in the cache is stored with a key which I use to identify it.  If you imagine I'm doing stuff like "select * from table" then storing the output in a DataTable, compressing it and storing in cache. Then I can take it out of the cache and perform queries against it.

Comment: In search of a solution to my issue I've shortlisted Redis, RavenDB and MongoDB as possible options.  I've also read somewhere that protobuf.net supports linq queries, has anybody ever combined protobuf and dynamic linq.